# Erro no código para popular JList com nomes de Arquivos de uma pasta

Tags: java, java-8

Não consigo passar um método para pegar o nome dos arquivos em uma pasta.

Tenho o código abaixo:

```
inicializar.addWindowListener(new WindowListener(){
       @Override
       public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0){

            DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
            JList lstvRel = new JList();
            lstvRel.setModel(dlm);
            ListarArquivos l = new ListarArquivos();
            dlm = l.listar(); //Erro nesta linha!!
            for(int i = 0; i < l.listar().size(); i++){
                lstvRel.getModel().getElementAt(i).toString();                    
            }    

        }
```

E a classe:

```
public class ListarArquivos {


    public void listar() {

        File dirArquivos = new File("C:\\Users\\lbell\\Desktop\\Turbo - teste");

        File[] Arquivos = dirArquivos.listFiles((File b) -> b.getName().endsWith(".xls") ||
                    b.getName().endsWith(".xlsx") ||
                    b.getName().endsWith(".xlsm") ||
                    b.getName().endsWith(".xlsb") ||
                    b.getName().endsWith(".ppt"));
    }

}
```

Comment: O método retorna `void`, o que está esperando que ele retorne?

Comment: Como o renan disse, o método listar é `void`, não há retorno, e você está tentando atribuir um retorno que não existe a uma variável.

Comment: Desculpem a ignorancia, sou novato em java e estou criando um programa gerador de relatorios. No caso entao como que eu poderia criar um retorno para o meu void gerar um array. A intenção é popular uma JList ao inicoar o programa.

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu objetivo é "popular uma JList ao inicoar o programa.", a implementação é um pouco diferente.

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso, usando os métodos que você já definiu, da pra fazer o seguinte:

Na classe desse seu objeto '**inicializar**', você deve criar e adicionar elementos na sua **DefaultListModel dlm** no construtor e colocar na sua JList. Um pequeno exemplo:

```
class Inicializar {

   JList lstRel;

   Inicializar(String dir) {

     // Cria a DefaultListModel
     DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<String>();

     // Cria a array de arquivos do diretorio
     File[] arquivos = (new File(dir)).listFiles((File b) -> b.getName().endsWith(".xls") ||
                b.getName().endsWith(".xlsx") ||
                b.getName().endsWith(".xlsm") ||
                b.getName().endsWith(".xlsb") ||
                b.getName().endsWith(".ppt"));

     // Adiciona os arquivos na DefaultListModel
     for(int i=0; i < arquivos.length; i++)
       addElement(arquivos[i].getName());

     // Coloca sua dlm em uma JList
     JList lstvRel = new JList(dlm);

   } 

   public JList getList() {

     return lstvRel;

  }

}
```

Comment: O exemplo consegui entender, mas como disse anteriormente, sou novato em Java.
Quando tentei utilizar algo semelhante, tive problema ao declarar no main da minha classe principal uma chamada para esta classe. Outra dúvida que fiquei é a seguinte: no WindowBuilder do meu projeto, inseri a JList que nomeei como lstvRel, como que posso fazer uma chamada para ela ser populada ao abrir o programa? Caso tenha algum link com tutorial agradeço, pois estou estudando para aprender.

Comment: Para iniciar é simples:
Inicializar init = new Inicializar("documentos/arquivos/");

Eu esqueci de te falar, mas o construtor é o responsável por instanciar a classe que foi definida (veja mais em: http://www.devmedia.com.br/construtores-em-java/28618). Ou seja, sempre que iniciar o programa você ira instanciar a classe Inicializar e, dessa forma, chamar o seu construtor (popular sua lista).

Assim, você pode pegar a JList dessa forma:
JList lstvRel = init.getList();